# Populate element class using object data

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to populate a couple of lement classes using data from an object:

HTML:

```
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td><span class="hoursspan"></span></td>
 <td><span class="partspan"></span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><span class="hoursspan"></span></td>
 <td><span class="partspan"></span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><span class="hoursspan"></span></td>
 <td><span class="partspan"></span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><span class="hoursspan"></span></td>
 <td><span class="partspan"></span></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Javascript:

```
var finalData = [{
"issue": "A",
"hours": 79,
"partcipantes": 33
}, {
"issue": "B",
"hours": 16,
"partcipantes": 10
}, {
"issue": "C",
"hours": 12,
"partcipantes": 10
}, {
"issue": "D",
"hours": 5,
"partcipantes": 8
}];

for (var w = 0; w < finalData.length; w++) {
document.getElementsByClassName("hoursspan")[w].innerHTML = finalData[w].hours;
document.getElementsByClassName("partspan")[w].innerHTML = finalData[w].partcipantes;
}
```

It works just fine in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emfuentes27/u8j8mde3/), but in my environment (SharePoint 2013 on Premises) I keep getting a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined`. I'm not what else to do, what could it be causing this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Count your HTML elements: getElementsByClassName('').length as well as the finalData length - compare, is there any difference? Do you execute the code after document is fully loaded?

Comment: Thanks @alex.mitchel, you were absolutely right! The issue is that in my scenario the table is created dynamically using `$.getJSON`, and even when I try to insert this data using `done()`, apparently the element is not completely loaded yet. Let's see what I can figure out, thanks!

Comment: Can you post your total code by now? If it's a matter of loading and executing the javascripts, you should be able to fix this by javascript promises (as $.getJSON already does already implicitely)